# Ajax call onchange of date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using daterangepicker.js, onchange of date i have to call the getchart method
when i change the date i need to call a getchart(), can anyone help me out in this
here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dateRangeSelector').daterangepicker(); //textbox id
        var start = Date.today().setTimeToNow(); 
        var end =  Date.today().setTimeToNow();
        var displayValue = start.toString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " - " + end.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        $('#dateRangeSelector').val(displayValue);

        var host = '<?=$host ?>'
        var dateRangeSelector = $("#dateRangeSelector").val();
        var dates = dateRangeSelector.split(" - ");
        var value = "'"+dates.join("' , '")+"'";
        var array = value.split(',');
        var startTime = array[0];
        var endTime = array[1];

       $.get(SITE_URL + 'admin/SystemMonitor/charts/getChartsData', {'host' : host,'startTime' : startTime,'endTime' : endTime}, function(response){
            console.log("viewCharts", response);
            obj = response;
            //bootbox.alert(obj.status, obj.label);
            if (obj.status == 'OK') {
                $('.one_half').show();
                showMonitoringServer(host, obj);

            } else {
               show_message('Show Chart Error -' +host, 'Unexpected error occured! Please try again later!', 'error' );
            }
        }, "json");
        });
```

Comment: use change handler for daterangeselector..
http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `onChange` event?

```
$('#dateRangeSelector').daterangepicker({ 
    onChange: function(){                  
        //do ajax stuff
    }
);
```

There seems to be a known issue with `onChange` getting called twice. If it hasn't been fixed in your version, you can always use:

```
$('#dateRangeSelector').on('blur', function(){
    //do ajax stuff
});
```

> I added a callback function for onChange now that you might be able use. Keep in mind that it may not fit your needs exactly because it will fire on EVERY change that occurs in the input. One-click range shortcuts will actually fire 2 change callbacks because this plugin simply triggers date changes on each datepicker, one at a time. Once this plugin is adopted by jQuery UI, I’m sure we’ll work that part out and have the rangepicker firing events as one widget. For now, you’ll need to set up your page with this issue in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dateRangeSelector').change(function(){
       $.get(SITE_URL + 'admin/SystemMonitor/charts/getChartsData', {'host' : host,'startTime' : startTime,'endTime' : endTime}, function(response){
            console.log("viewCharts", response);
            obj = response;
            //bootbox.alert(obj.status, obj.label);
            if (obj.status == 'OK') {
                $('.one_half').show();
                showMonitoringServer(host, obj);

            } else {
               show_message('Show Chart Error -' +host, 'Unexpected error occured! Please try again later!', 'error' );
            }
        }, "json");

 });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$( "#dateRangeSelector" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

You can also have a look at the Jquery API: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation itself shows:

[**Follow this link of documentation**](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

```
$('#dp5').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    if (ev.date.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf()){
         ....
    }
});
```

so you need to do this way:

```
$('#dateRangeSelector').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $.get(SITE_URL + 'admin/SystemMonitor/charts/getChartsData', {'host' : host,'startTime' : startTime,'endTime' : endTime}, function(response){
        console.log("viewCharts", response);
        obj = response;
        //bootbox.alert(obj.status, obj.label);
        if (obj.status == 'OK') {
            $('.one_half').show();
            showMonitoringServer(host, obj);

        } else {
           show_message('Show Chart Error -' +host, 'Unexpected error occured! Please try again later!', 'error' );
        }
    }, "json");
});
```